# Why isn't my reverse(); function working?

Tags: c, reverse, singly-linked-list, circular-list, function-definition

I'm writing a program in C for reversing a circular singly linked list. I keep getting segmentation fault for some reason. I'm sure the problem is with the `reverse` function as I tried commenting the function call, the program works fine.

For my `reverse()` function, I have used 3 pointers: `prev`, `next` and `curr`. The logic is that I'll run a loop till `curr` takes the address of `head`, which will be stored in the `link` part of the last node since it is a circular linked list. I'll keep updating `curr->link` using `prev` pointer which will change its link from the next to its previous node.

When the loop breaks, `head->link = prev;` and `head = prev;` will update the respective addresses such that they point to the first node of the reversed list.

```
//reversing CLL

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
} *head;

void reverse() {
    struct node *prev = NULL, *curr = head, *next;
        
    while (curr != head) {
        next = curr->link;
        curr->link = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
        
    head->link = prev;
    head = prev; 
}

void createList(int n) {
    int i, data;    
    
    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        
    struct node *ptr = head, *temp;
            
    printf("Enter data of node 1\t");
    scanf("%d", &data);
            
    head->data = data;
    head->link = NULL;
            
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        
        printf("Enter data of node %d\t", i);
        scanf("%d", &data);
                        
        temp->data = data;
        temp->link = NULL;
                        
        ptr->link = temp;
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    ptr->link = head;
}

void disp() {
    struct node *ptr = head;
        
    do {
        printf("%d\t", ptr->data);   //gdb debugger shows problem is in this line
        ptr = ptr->link;
    } while (ptr != head);
}

int main() {
    int n;
        
    printf("Enter no of nodes to be created\t");
    scanf("%d", &n);
        
    createList(n);
            
    printf("\n\nList is displayed below!\n");
        
    disp();
            
    printf("\n\nReversing list ...\n");
            
    reverse();   // on commenting this call, disp() function 
                 // works accurately showing node data non-reversed
                  
    disp();
            
    printf("\n\nList successfully reversed!\n");
}
```

Comment: Debugger shows that the error lies in printf("%d\t",ptr->data); and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how.

Comment: @Mohsin When does the condition of the loop while(curr!=head)  evaluate to true?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The loop starts with curr pointing to the first node. It runs till the last node when curr takes the address of head since it is a circular linked list so the "link" part of the last node points to the first node.

Comment: You are missing the point of Vlad's comment. `curr = head; while(curr!=head)`. With that code the `while` condition is always immediately false and thus the body of the loop never ever runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop in the `reverse()` function exits immediately because `curr` is initialized to the value of `head` so the test `while (curr != head)` is false at the first iteration.

`reverse()` then sets `head->link` to `NULL` and finally `head` is also set to `NULL` (the initial value of `prev`), which explains the segmentation fault in the subsequent `disp()` function where you use a `do { } while (pre != head)` that cannot handle an empty list.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

struct node *reverse(struct node *head) {
    struct node *prev = NULL, *curr = head;

    if (head) {
        do {
            struct node *next = curr->link;
            curr->link = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = next;
        } while (curr != head);
        curr->link = prev;
        head = prev;
    }
    return head;
}

struct node *createList(int n) {
    struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL, *temp;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data = 0;
        temp->link = NULL;

        printf("Enter data of node %d\t", i);
        scanf("%d", &temp->data);

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
        } else {
            tail->link = temp;
        }
        tail = temp;
        temp->link = head;
    }
    return head;
}

void disp(struct node *head) {
    if (head) {
        struct node *ptr = head;
        do {
            printf("%d\t", ptr->data);
            ptr = ptr->link;
        } while (ptr != head);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *head;
    int n = 0;

    printf("Enter no of nodes to be created\t");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    head = createList(n);

    printf("\n\nList is displayed below!\n");
    disp(head);

    printf("\n\nReversing list ...\n");

    head = reverse(head);

    disp(head);

    printf("\n\nList successfully reversed!\n");

    // should free the list
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understood my mistake in the while(curr!=head) statement. I don't quite understand the reasoning behind the segmentation fault but I'll do that research myself. Could you explain to me what if (head) means? I've seen this everywhere but I don't understand it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mohsin: At the start of the `reverse` function, `prev` is set to `NULL`. Since the loop does not iterate at all, the last 2 statements `head->link = prev; head = prev;`  set `head->link` to `NULL` and finally `head` to `NULL` as well. You then call `disp()` which initializes its local variable `ptr` to `head`, which is `NULL` and `printf("%d\t", ptr->data);` causes a segmentation fault because you dereference a null pointer trying to access `ptr->data`. `if (head)` tests if the pointer `head` is a true value. Pointers are true if the are non null. The test is equivalent to `if (head != NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is a bad idea to use the global variable `head`

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
} *head;
```

In this case the functions depend on the global variable and you can not use more than one list in a program.

Due to this initialization

```
struct node *prev = NULL, *curr = head, *next;
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the condition of the while loop

```
while (curr != head) {
```

is never evaluates to true because initially the pointer `curr` is equal to the pointer `head`.

Moreover if the list is empty then this statement

```
head->link = prev;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the list can be declared in main and then reversed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

size_t assign( struct node **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        struct node *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->link;
        free( tmp );
    }
    
    size_t total = 0;
    
    struct node *first = NULL;
    
    while ( total < n && ( *head = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        ( *head )->data  = a[total];
        ( *head )->link  = NULL;
        ++total;
        
        if ( first == NULL ) first = *head;
        
        head = &( *head )->link;
    }
    
    if ( first != NULL ) *head = first;
    
    return total;
}

void display( const struct node *head )
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        const struct node *current = head;
        do
        {
            printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
        } while ( ( current = current->link ) != head );
    }       
    
    puts( "null" );
}

struct node * reverse( struct node **head )
{
    if ( *head )
    {
        struct node *last = *head;
        struct node *prev = NULL;

        while ( ( *head )->link != last )
        {
            struct node *current = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->link;
            current->link = prev;
            prev = current;
        }
        
        ( *head )->link = prev;
        last->link = *head;
    }
    
    return *head;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    
    assign( &head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    
    display( head );
    
    display( reverse( &head ) );
    
    display( reverse( &head ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Comment: Okay I have some questions. Please bear with me.                                                                       1. Could you elaborate on why making "head" global is a bad practice?                                     2. Why have you used arrays in this program?                                                                            3. Why do you use *head instead of just 'head'? I changed the loop to do { } while { }, that solved the curr!=head initialization problem but I want to know why you write code like this. Is my approach bad?

Comment: @Mohsin Using a global variable is a bad idea because in this case you can have only one global variable with that name. As a result a user of your list will be unable to have for example two lists simultaneously. Also functions will depend on the global variable. I used an array only that to simplify filling of the list with any data,